# Top navagation menu

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

Hi I would like to edit my Top navagation menu so it appears like the "Shop" section on http://www.truevalue.com/ . How can I do this? Is there an extension for this? I am currently using the Free classic theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steven Lynn,

```
can you try
```

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html

Or http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-menu-by-elevensoft.html
.

Comment: The first link is broken. Does that extension work with 1.9?

Comment: check link ,it working in magento ce 1.9

Comment: i will give these a try and let you know if they worked for. Thanks for the reply.